# Unable to connect two call back functions together in dash app

Tags: django, plotly, loading, plotly-dash

Hello I am working on a dash app for the first time and I am unable to fix 
an issue that I am facing. I have a front-end that takes the user input, does some calculation, stores the result in a hidden div and then updates the graph.

The app loads fine however it runs into an error as soon as I hit the submit button. Below is the code I have written. It looks like both the callback functions triggers at the same time.

```
app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()), className="nine columns")
        ], className="three columns"),
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    html.P("Select Month Range:"),
                ],
                    className="two columns"
                ),

                html.Div([
                    dcc.RangeSlider(
                        id='month_slider',
                        # updatemode='drag',
                        # count=1,
                        min=1,
                        max=maxmarks,
                        step=1,
                        value=[maxmarks - 1, maxmarks],
                        marks=tags,
                        pushable=1
                    ),

                ],
                    className="six columns",
                    style={})
            ],
                className="twelve columns",
                style={
                    'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA',
                    'padding-top': '1.5em',
                    'padding-bottom': '1em'
                }),
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='demographics',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'All 18-49', 'value': '18-49'},
                            {'label': 'Female 25-54', 'value': '25-54F'},
                            {'label': 'All 25-54', 'value': '25-54'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Demographics",
                    )
                ],
                    className="two columns",
                    style={}),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='ID',
                        options=[
                            {'label': '200', 'value': 200, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '250', 'value': 250, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '300', 'value': 300, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '350', 'value': 350, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '400', 'value': 400, 'type': 'number'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select ID",
                    )
                ],
                    className="two columns",
                    style={}),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Income',
                        options=[
                            {'label': '50,000', 'value': 50000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '100,000', 'value': 100000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '200,000', 'value': 200000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '350,000', 'value': 350000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '500,000', 'value': 500000, 'type': 'number'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Income",
                    )
                ],
                    className="two columns",
                    style={}),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Frquency',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'None per week, 'value': 0, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': 'Once per Week', 'value': 1, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': 'Thrice per Week', 'value': 3, 'type': 'number'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Frequency",
                    )
                ],
                    className="two columns",
                    style={}),
                html.Div([
                    html.Button('Submit', id='submit_button', className='twelve columns',
                                style={'background-color': '#2D91C3', 'color': 'white', 'font-size': '1em'})
                ],
                    className="two columns",
                    style={}),
            ],
                className="twelve columns",
                style={
                    'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA',
                    'padding-top': '1em',
                    'padding-bottom': '1.5em'
                })
        ], className="nine columns", style={})
    ], className="twelve columns"),

    # dcc.graph layout

    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='example-graph', config={"displayModeBar": False, "scrollZoom": False})

        ],
            className="six columns",
            style={'border-right': 'thin grey solid', 'border-left': 'thin grey solid',
                   'border-top': 'thin grey solid'}),

    html.Div(id='intermediate-value1', style={'display': 'none'})
])]

@app.callback(
    Output("intermediate-value1", "children"),
    [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
    [
        State("month_slider", "value"),
        State("demographics", "value"),
        State("Income", "value"),
        State("Frequency", "value"),
    ],
)
def clean_data(n_clicks, month_range, demo, inc, fre_cap):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        employee_data_temp = employee_data.copy()
        start_date = month_range[0]
        end_date = month_range[1]
        mask1 = employee_data_temp["total_months"] == int(end_date - start_date)
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.loc[mask1]
        mask2 = (
            (employee_data_temp["demographic"] == demo)
            & (employee_data_temp["freq_cap"] == fre_cap)
            & (employee_data_temp["total_incressions"] == inc)
        )
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.loc[mask2]
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.sort_values(by=["reach"])
        employee_data_temp["income_percent"] = (employee_data_temp["reach"] / 955000) * 100
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
        return employee_data_temp.to_json(date_format="iso", orient="split")
    else:
        return []

@app.callback(Output("example-graph", "figure"),
              [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
              [State("intermediate-value1", "children"),
               State("Income", "value")])

def update_graph(n_clicks, employee_data_temp, inc):
    t.sleep(2)
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        dff = pd.read_json(employee_data_temp, orient="split")
        max_income = dff["income_percent"].iloc[9]
        max_income = max_income.round(2)
        trace = Scatter(
            y=dff["income_percent"], x=dff["inc"], line=plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line(color="#1a2d46"), mode="lines"
        )
        layout1 = Layout(
            plot_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
            paper_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
            height=450,
            title="Digital Reach - " + str(max_income) + " " + "%",
            xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, showline=True, zeroline=True, fixedrange=True, title="Total Income"),
            yaxis=dict(showline=True, fixedrange=True, zeroline=True, title="Income (%)"),
            margin=plotly.graph_objs.layout.Margin(t=45, l=50, r=50),
        )
        return Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout1)
    else:
        return []
```

Below is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\django_projects\tvnz_dash_app\src\dash_app\incrementor\views.py", line 21, in dispatcher
    response = server.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1073, in dispatch
    response.set_data(self.callback_map[output]['callback'](*args))
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 969, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\django_projects\tvnz_dash_app\src\dash_app\incrementor\router.py", line 699, in update_graph
    dff = pd.read_json(employee_data_temp, orient="split")
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 413, in read_json
    path_or_buf, encoding=encoding, compression=compression,
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 232, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

What I want is that the function should run when a user click a submit button and as the update graph function is dependent on the clean data function it should not run until and unless the clean data function is finished completing.

Please can some one help me to figure what am I missing here and help to resolve the issue.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

NEW UPDATED FUNCTIONS

```
@app.callback(
    Output("intermediate-value1", "children"),
    [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
    [
        State("month_slider", "value"),
        State("demographics", "value"),
        State("digital_impressions", "value"),
        State("digital_frequency", "value"),
    ],
)

def get_match(n_clicks, month_range, demo, tarps):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        some long python script data calculatation
        return match_data_temp.to_json(date_format="iso", orient="split")



@app.callback(
    Output("intermediate-value2", "children"),
    [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
    [
        State("month_slider", "value"),
        State("demographics", "value"),
        State("digital_impressions", "value"),
        State("digital_frequency", "value"),
    ],
)


def clean_data(n_clicks, month_range, demo, inc, fre_cap):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        employee_data_temp = employee_data.copy()
        start_date = month_range[0]
        end_date = month_range[1]
        mask1 = employee_data_temp["total_months"] == int(end_date - start_date)
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.loc[mask1]
        mask2 = (
            (employee_data_temp["demographic"] == demo)
            & (employee_data_temp["freq_cap"] == fre_cap)
            & (employee_data_temp["total_incressions"] == inc)
        )
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.loc[mask2]
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.sort_values(by=["reach"])
        employee_data_temp["income_percent"] = (employee_data_temp["reach"] / 955000) * 100
        employee_data_temp = employee_data_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
        return employee_data_temp.to_json(date_format="iso", orient="split")




@app.callback(
    Output("intermediate-value3", "children"),
    [
        Input("month_slider", "value"),
        Input("demographics", "value"),
        Input("intermediate-value2", "children"),
        Input("intermediate-value1", "children"),
    ],
)
def get_match_overlap(month_range, demo, match_data_temp, employee_data_temp):

    overlap_match = pd.read_json(match_data_temp, orient="split")
    overlap_employee = pd.read_json(employee_data_temp, orient="split")
    some long python calculatation
    return final.to_json(date_format="iso", orient="split")


@app.callback(
    Output("example-graph2", "figure"),
    [Input("intermediate-value3", "children"), Input("intermediate-value2", "children")],
)
def update_graph(final, match_data_temp):
    if final is not None:
        dff_overlap = pd.read_json(final, orient="split")
        dff_match_data = pd.read_json(match_data_temp, orient="split")
        overlap = Scatter(
            y=dff_overlap["final"],
            x=dff_overlap["percentage"],
            name="tile",
            line=plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line(color="red"),
            mode="lines",
        )
        layout1 = Layout(
            plot_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
            paper_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
            title="title",
            height=550,
            xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, showline=True, zeroline=False, fixedrange=True, title="% Campaign Completion", range=[0, 100]),
            yaxis=dict(showline=True, fixedrange=True, zeroline=False, title="Audience Reached (%)", range=[0, (reach_increment + 10)]),
            margin=plotly.graph_objs.layout.Margin(t=45, l=50, r=50),
        )

        linear = Scatter(
            y=dff_match_data["Final"],
            x=dff_match_data["percentage"],
            name="title",
            line=plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line(color="black"),
            mode="lines",
        )
        return Figure(data=[overlap, linear], layout=layout1)

@app.callback(Output("example-graph", "figure"),
              [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
              [State("intermediate-value2", "children"),
               State("Income", "value")])

def update_graph(n_clicks, employee_data_temp, inc):

    if employee_data_temp is not None:
        dff = pd.read_json(employee_data_temp, orient="split")
        trace = Scatter(
            y=dff["income_percent"], x=dff["inc"], line=plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line(color="#1a2d46"), mode="lines"
        )
        layout1 = Layout(
            plot_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
            paper_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
            height=450,
            title="Digital - " + str(max_income) + " " + "%",
            xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, showline=True, zeroline=True, fixedrange=True, title="Total Income"),
            yaxis=dict(showline=True, fixedrange=True, zeroline=True, title="Income (%)"),
            margin=plotly.graph_objs.layout.Margin(t=45, l=50, r=50),
        )
        return Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a few minor things first. There are some syntax errors here, though they may not be in your original file. You have a missing ID, because `id='Frequency',` has a typo. Easy fix. I got numerous warnings about an incorrect prop for `Dropdown`, which I solved by removing the `type='number'` you were passing in for each dropdown option. I also changed the default return value for `update_graph` to an empty dictionary, which resolved another type error.

Now for bigger things. You are triggering two callbacks using the same button. The first deals with the data, and stores it in a hidden div. The second sleeps long enough to allow the first one to finish, and then runs on what's in the hidden div. The problem is that the second callback will pull in the contents of that hidden div as soon as it runs, and the fact that it sleeps does not change the value it works with **even if** that value updates before the sleep timer ends.

The fix here would be to combine callbacks. You can remove the hidden div, and simply do all the work start to finish in the single callback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason I am doing this because I am using the same dataframe in other call backs and hence had to store that in the hidden div. Any other way to approach this limitation. This was just one of the callback I am using in my app

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you could make the `Input` for your second callback the `children` value of the hidden div. That way you know it's been updated.

Comment: thanks a lot again for the response. I followed the instructions and did exactly what you asked for, however I still get the same error

Comment: You may need to include a check for the contents of that hidden div for when the callback initializes. It will fire once without the `Input` triggering it, so you may need something just like your check `if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:` but for the data.

Comment: I have used that as well but it still goes into same error. I have updated the codes as how I am using now

Comment: I see your update, but it does not include something like `if df_digital_temp is not None:`. Have you added that?

Comment: Apologies, I might have missed that. I presume this would go for the update_graph function. I added the above condition, it does not give any error on the app load, however it does not render a graph. It does run the clean_data function but not the update_graph function. I have tried both using just this condition and combining the condition with n_clicks condition as well. Once again, thanks a lot. I am very new to dash and your inputs are great help

Comment: Would you update with the latest changes to the functions for me? I'm curious why it isn't even running the second callback, and maybe I can see a reason after the changes.

Comment: I have updated the whole sequence of the dash callback functions. I have removed the long python codes. This should pretty much give you the idea about what I am trying to do. The app does work even after the error but It always stay in the updating mode. Because of it I am not able to add a loading component to the app. Thanks again for the response and all the help. Please let me know in case you need anything else.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify the `Input`s at all? I see something of a sequence as the intermediate values are updated, but some are also used in later callbacks. Could you move some of those values to `State`? For example, `update_graph` uses the `submit_button` as an input value, but could you remove that and just use `Input('intermediate-value2', 'children')`?

Comment: I tried that. It gives me an error in the `get_match_overlap` function for `overlap_match = pd.read_json(match_data_temp, orient="split")` as I believe it gets triggered as soon  I launch the app

Comment: The same error you were getting elsewhere? Try using `if match_data_temp is not None`: in that callback, too. Really, any callback that could have a `None` value needs that condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort. It seems finally we have achieved what we wanted to achieve. It is working as expected now without error and I was able to add loading component. In addition to `match_data_temp is not None` I also added `employee_data_temp is not none` too. Side question if you dont mind, is it possible to add our own logo instead of what dash provides for loading component. But again, thanks heaps for all the help

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! As far as I know, you cannot add a custom logo for the loading component, and need to use one of their icons,  'graph', 'cube', 'circle', 'dot', or 'default'.